# Dapp Arcitecture

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, dapp-development

Actually I am new to Ethreum Blockchain
I have been created some contract but still I am not clear about How Dapp's Architecture
Like get An example
I need to Created A market Place where People can Buy and sell things directly using My contract But I don't want them to download whole block chain neither I want to download Whole Block chain on server
so Then I saw metamask which gives gives a way to do transaction without downloading whole block chain so
can you give me any idea how to implement this example

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it seems you cannot do this. As per my understanding the main principle on a public blockchain is that all participants manages all the blocks (even when it does not contain their own info) so that the chain is actually validated everywhere.
Conceptually, the blockchain is a replicated database, where the replication is what makes it secured. 
However, end users can avoid being full participants by just querying the other nodes for info via the P2P network.

Good luck

Comment: For the P2P participation only refer to https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Peer-to-Peer. Seems to use go language

Answer (score -1):

Check out the video tutorials by shlomi zeltsinger on Building Ethereum dapp using Solidity.This tutorial initially teaches you how to deploy contracts through the solidity online compiler and the metamask plugin (currently only for chrome browser) and later uses the meteor framework to build the dapp. You can find the link [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLH4m2oS2ratdoHFEkGvwvd7TkeTv4sa7Z)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.